# Tk treeview column sort

Tags: python, sorting, treeview, tkinter

Is there a way to sort the entries in a [Tk Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) by clicking the column? Surprisingly, I could not find any documentation/tutorial for this.

Comment: Along with #tcl, other apt resources for Tkinter research are the Tkinter mailing list and Wiki.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This did not work in python3. Since the Variable was passed by reference, all lambdas ended up refering to the same, last, element in columns.

This did the trick for me:

```
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                     treeview_sort_column(treeview, _col, False))
```

Comment: Works in Python 2.7, too.

Comment: It took me a while to understand this answer, so I re-wrote it with a full example. I would have preferred to edit this answer, but it has just got rejected :/

Comment: When I first visited this page I stopped reading after I saw Sridhar Ratnakumar's answer. I couldn't get it to work when using the for loop. I could make it work if I added the headings one by one. I'm glad I revisited this page. The minor change worked perfectly!

Answer (score 30):

[patthoyts](http://www.patthoyts.tk/) from `#tcl` pointed out that the TreeView Tk demo program had the sort functionality. Here's the Python equivalent of it:

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
               treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

[...]
columns = ('name', 'age')
treeview = ttk.TreeView(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda: \
                     treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False))
[...]
```

Comment: This answer did not work for me on Python 2.7 - it always passed in the name of the final column to `treeview_sort_column`. [The solution that madonius posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724912/901641) did work for me on Python 2.7.

Comment: Yep. In the other answers there is a nice explanation for why this is not working

Comment: Change "False" in the 2nd to last line to "True" to allow the first click to reverse the list from its initial (organized) state. For example, if your list is initially in A->Z, pressing the menu will do noting because reverse is false. You'll have to click again to revere. This is fixed by changing that arg to True.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275988   - this one works much better because the original code can throw '_tkinter.TclError: Display column #0 cannot be set' if to click on the very first column in the treeview.

Comment: The reason this fails and the last value of col is used by the lambda is "late binding". To keep the individual values of col so each column's lambda behaves differently, force "early binding" by placing an argument directly after the word "lambda" and use that after the colon to preserve each value of col outside of the loop (See @madonius' answer).

Answer (score 6):

**madonius** is right, but here you have the full example and a proper, understandable explanation

The answer provided by **Sridhar Ratnakumar** does not work in python3 (and apparently in python2.7): since the variable is passed by reference, all lambdas end up referring to the same, last, element in columns.

You just need to change this `for loop`:

```
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                     treeview_sort_column(treeview, _col, False))
```

**And the same change has to be applied to the lambda function inside treeview_sort_column**

So the complete solution would look like this:

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                 treeview_sort_column(tv, _col, not reverse))

[...]
columns = ('name', 'age')
treeview = ttk.TreeView(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                     treeview_sort_column(treeview, _col, False))
[...]
```

Comment: Just as a quick addition: `l.sort(reverse=reverse, key=lambda tup: int(tup[0]))` can correctly sort by numerical values (or change to what is needed), additionally  `l.sort(reverse=False, key=lambda tup: int(tup[1]))` will restore the table to its original order.

Comment: In case you have some columns as numeric and some as string then use this code with try catch block: `try:  # in case the value is numeric
   l.sort(reverse=reverse, key=lambda tup: float(tup[0]))
  except ValueError:  # catches failure means it was string and need to be handled as string
   l.sort(reverse=reverse)`

Comment: What does command=lambda?

Comment: I think it sorts by ascii so if the first character is capital, it will have that one come first even if it is later in the alphabet (for example, a word starting with T would display before a word starting with a). Anyone know the best way to approach this without manipulating how the outlook appears?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue while trying to create a view for DB,
Inspired by [Sridhar Ratnakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55246/sridhar-ratnakumar) Answer,
I rather take the same principles that he did and to upgrade the class Treeview.

```
class MyTreeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def heading(self, column, sort_by=None, **kwargs):
        if sort_by and not hasattr(kwargs, 'command'):
            func = getattr(self, f"_sort_by_{sort_by}", None)
            if func:
                kwargs['command'] = partial(func, column, False)
        return super().heading(column, **kwargs)

    def _sort(self, column, reverse, data_type, callback):
        l = [(self.set(k, column), k) for k in self.get_children('')]
        l.sort(key=lambda t: data_type(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
        for index, (_, k) in enumerate(l):
            self.move(k, '', index)
        self.heading(column, command=partial(callback, column, not reverse))

    def _sort_by_num(self, column, reverse):
        self._sort(column, reverse, int, self._sort_by_num)

    def _sort_by_name(self, column, reverse):
        self._sort(column, reverse, str, self._sort_by_name)

    def _sort_by_date(self, column, reverse):
        def _str_to_datetime(string):
            return datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self._sort(column, reverse, _str_to_datetime, self._sort_by_date)

...
# Some code
...

treeview.heading('number', text='number', sort_by='num')
treeview.heading('name', text='name', sort_by='name')
treeview.heading('date', text='date', sort_by='date')
```

Just puting this here :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the customised treeview. I used it to customise it for my need. I had a treeview containing 10 columns for expenses and income. Each column had either strings, numbers, numbers with thousand separators (say 1,000), row code containg multiple decimal values (say 2.5.1.6). I am now able to sort them nicely. Working code is attached below as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

make this small change to the function if you have integers in your table
it will look like this.

```
def treeview_sort_column(treeview: ttk.Treeview, col, reverse: bool):
    """
    to sort the table by column when clicking in column
    """
    try:
        data_list = [
            (int(treeview.set(k, col)), k) for k in treeview.get_children("")
        ]
    except Exception:
        data_list = [(treeview.set(k, col), k) for k in treeview.get_children("")]

    data_list.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(data_list):
        treeview.move(k, "", index)

    # reverse sort next time
    treeview.heading(
        column=col,
        text=col,
        command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(
            treeview, _col, not reverse
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code to sort columns that contain string, numbers, numbers with thousand separators, code with multiple decimal values.

[image]

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK
from functools import partial
import datetime as objDateTime

class MyTreeview(objTTK.Treeview):
    def heading(self, column, sort_by=None, **kwargs):
        if sort_by and not hasattr(kwargs, 'command'):
            func = getattr(self, f"_sort_by_{sort_by}", None)
            if func:
                kwargs['command'] = partial(func, column, False)
            # End of if
        # End of if
        return super().heading(column, **kwargs)
    # End of heading()

    def _sort(self, column, reverse, data_type, callback):
        l = [(self.set(k, column), k) for k in self.get_children('')]
        l.sort(key=lambda t: data_type(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
        for index, (_, k) in enumerate(l):
            self.move(k, '', index)
        # End of for loop
        self.heading(column, command=partial(callback, column, not reverse))
    # End of _sort()

    def _sort_by_num(self, column, reverse):
        self._sort(column, reverse, int, self._sort_by_num)
    # End of _sort_by_num()

    def _sort_by_name(self, column, reverse):
        self._sort(column, reverse, str, self._sort_by_name)
    # End of _sort_by_num()

    def _sort_by_date(self, column, reverse):
        def _str_to_datetime(string):
            return objDateTime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d")
        # End of _str_to_datetime()
        
        self._sort(column, reverse, _str_to_datetime, self._sort_by_date)
    # End of _sort_by_num()
    
    def _sort_by_multidecimal(self, column, reverse):
        def _multidecimal_to_str(string):
            arrString = string.split(".")
            strNum = ""
            for iValue in arrString:
                strValue = f"{int(iValue):02}"
                strNum = "".join([strNum, str(strValue)])
            # End of for loop
            strNum = "".join([strNum, "0000000"])
            return int(strNum[:8])
        # End of _multidecimal_to_str()
        
        self._sort(column, reverse, _multidecimal_to_str, self._sort_by_multidecimal)
    # End of _sort_by_num() 

    def _sort_by_numcomma(self, column, reverse):
        def _numcomma_to_num(string):
            return int(string.replace(",", ""))
        # End of _numcomma_to_num()
        
        self._sort(column, reverse, _numcomma_to_num, self._sort_by_numcomma)
    # End of _sort_by_num() 

# End of class MyTreeview

objWindow = objTK.Tk()

arrlbHeader = ["Type" , "Description", "C. Name", "C. code", "Amount", "Day", "Month ", "Year", "Date", "Comments"]
treeview = MyTreeview(columns=arrlbHeader, show="headings")
arrRows = [["Expenses", "Curds milk", "Dairy products", "2.5.2.1", "456", "31", "8", "2021", "2021-08-31", ""],
["Expenses", "Aug", "Maid", "2.12.4", "1,000", "31", "8", "2021", "2021-08-31", ""],
["Expenses", "Aug", "Water", "2.12.8", "200", "31", "8", "2021", "2021-08-31", "AAA"],
["Income", "Aug", "Electricity", "2.12.2", "190", "31", "8", "2021", "2021-08-31", "OMG"],
["Expenses", "Aug - garbage collection", "Miscellaneous", "2.12.9", "20", "31", "8", "2021", "2021-08-31", "Test1"],
["Expenses", "Bread", "Bakery", "2.5.1.1", "10", "29", "8", "2021", "2021-08-29", ""],
["Income", "Veggies", "Vegetables", "2.5.2.7", "21", "28", "8", "2021", "2021-08-28", ""],
["Expenses", "Groceries", "Grains", "2.5.2.3", "76", "28", "8", "2021", "2021-08-28", "Test"],
["Expenses", "Phenyl", "Toiletries", "2.16", "34", "28", "8", "2021", "2021-08-28", ""]]
arrColWidth = [57, 53, 85, 69, 55, 30, 45, 33, 68, 100]
arrColAlignment = ["center", "e", "w", "w", "e", "center", "center", "center", "center", "w"]

arrSortType = ["name", "name", "name", "multidecimal", "numcomma", "num", "num", "num", "date", "name"]
for iCount in range(len(arrlbHeader)):
    strHdr = arrlbHeader[iCount]
    treeview.heading(strHdr, text=strHdr.title(), sort_by=arrSortType[iCount])
    treeview.column(arrlbHeader[iCount], width=arrColWidth[iCount], stretch=True, anchor=arrColAlignment[iCount])
# End of for loop

treeview.pack()

for iCount in range(len(arrRows)):
    treeview.insert("", "end", values=arrRows[iCount])
# End of for loop

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda funcWinSer: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the solution that **madonius** proposed works nicely but sorts strings in alphabetical order by first placing upper case letters then lowercase letters.

This is an expected behaviour if you know how computers treat letters (for more information about this behaviour [Why does Python sort put upper case items first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247521/why-does-python-sort-put-upper-case-items-first)).

To sort alphabetically strings without considering upper case letters different from lowercase letter, add .lower() in the treeview_sort_column function.

Full code:

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col).lower(), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
             treeview_sort_column(tv, _col, not reverse))

[...]
columns = ('name', 'age')
treeview = ttk.TreeView(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                 treeview_sort_column(treeview, _col, False))
[...]
```