# List sorted by categories in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, detailsview

I'm building a graphical program that will need to show files on both the user's computer and on a remote server. I'm using Tkinter, and I'm definitely a novice with this toolkit. I want to have the files displayed in a box similar to what you would get from a "Details" view in Windows, so that each file has several categories of info(think name, type, size, permissions, etc.) about it and so that the list can be sorted by category, ascending or descending.

What objects in Tkinter (if any) could I use to accomplish this? Is there a tutorial or an existing project that implements something similar with Tkinter?

I'm not sure if my description makes sense, so here's a screenshot of what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeView widget should help you

- http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html
- http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-treeview
- http://m-eken.com/2010/03/02/treeview-in-python-tkinter/

Yeah , So already has one on this topic

- [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

You should be able to get started from these pointers

Comment: Sorry, I guess more than anything I was really looking for the name of the widget. Thanks for the links