# Is there a Tkinter widget equivalent to .NET's ListView control?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In .NET, there is the ListView control, which displays a multicolumn list of items with clickable column headings one can use to sort the list in ascending or descending order by column. I need a scrollable Tkinter widget with exactly that behavior, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the standard Tkinter module with even similar functionality. This seems like a strange oversight. Is there a module out there with a widget like this? A cross-platform solution would be most desirable, but it's most important that the widget function well on Windows (XP and 7).

Comment: Tkinter is very minimalistic. It works well for simple front-ends, but if you need more fancy stuff, you have to combine the basic widgets into what you need (quite some work, and quite nasty) or use a richer GUI toolkit.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a simple-to-implement Python GUI toolkit that includes a widget/control like this?

Comment: @delnan: while I agree that Tkinter is slightly minimalistic, creating a rich GUI is not all that painful. Tkinter is like Home Depot to other toolkits IKEA. Less pre-made widgets, but more flexibility when you need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a modern version of tkinter you can use the [ttk.Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget.

Comment: P.S. Sorting by column header can be done using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort

Comment: This works for me, thank you. I should note that the sorting by column header code does not work as written, though. Only the last value of 'col' in the for loop gets set as the value of 'col' in the treeview_sort_column function assigned to the button commands. To solve this, I used the code: 
    command = lambda col=col: treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False)