# Python 3.3.2 tkinter ttk TreeView per-column sorting only sorts by last column?

Tags: python, sorting, treeview, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to get a simplistic ttk TreeView table going with per-column sorting using the heading 'command' tag, but it doesn't seem to work right. I'm using the answer to this question for implementing the functionality: [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    print('sorting %s!' % col)
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        print('Moving Index:%r, Value:%r, k:%r' % (index, val, k))
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

cols = ('name', 'path', 'time', 'pb')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")
listbox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show="headings")
for each in ('name', 'path', 'time','pb'):
    listbox.heading(each,text=each.capitalize(),command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(listbox, each, False))
    listbox.column( each, width=tk.font.Font().measure(each.title() ))
    if not each == 'path':
        listbox.column(each,stretch=False)
    if not each == 'name':
        listbox.column( each, anchor='center')

listbox.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem I am running into is every time I run this, it only sorts by the last column, not by the column your clicking on (verified with the print statement in the treeview_sort_column function). Output I get from clicking on any column in the resulting window:

```
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
```

If I change from dynamic creation of each command in the for loop to explicit ones by adding this after the loop then it works as expected (i.e. each column sorts itself).

```
listbox.heading('name', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(listbox, 'name', False))
listbox.heading('path', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(listbox, 'path', False))
listbox.heading('time', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(listbox, 'time', False))
listbox.heading('pb', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(listbox, 'pb', False))
```

produces:

```
sorting name!
sorting name!
sorting path!
sorting path!
sorting time!
sorting time!
sorting pb!
sorting pb!
```

Obviously this is a very simplistic example, and my final application actually inserts data into the columns (also has more columns) but since I can't even get this simplified version to work, I'm at a loss. What is wrong with my loop that's causing the lambda functions to get screwed up?

My system:

- Windows 7, 64 bit
- Python 3.3.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use lambda in other way. In your code every lambda gets a pointer to the same variable, that is why all functions do the same thing. You should, e.g, copy variable to make lambda unique. An example how to do it:

```
for each in ('name', 'path', 'time','pb'):
    listbox.heading(each,text=each.capitalize(),command=lambda each_=each: treeview_sort_column(listbox, each_, False))
```

Simple example:

```
funcs = []
for item in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'):
    funcs.append(lambda : print(item))
for f in funcs:
    f()
```

It prints:

```
ghi
ghi
ghi
```

But version with fixed lambda:

```
funcs = []
for item in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'):
    funcs.append(lambda item_=item: print(item_))
for f in funcs:
    f()
```

prints

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: That would be it. Strange, because I thought I tried this and it worked normally. However I just tried your example in both Python 2 and 3, and it performs the same in both (though in 2 I have to make a 'print' function).