# python ttk treeview sort numbers

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm trying to use the ttk.Treeview sort function illustrated in the answer to this question ([Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)) and it works just fine for strings like 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', etc., but when I try to sort numbers it ends up showing up like this:

```
1
10
11
2
3
...
```

I'd like for the data to be sorted such that the output is:

```
1
2
3
...
10
11
```

I know that the values in the treeview columns are strings and that I'm most likely going to need to convert them to integers before sorting, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types) method, [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function accept optional `key` parameter. The return value of the function is used as comparison key.

Specifying `key` function that convert the treeview item into number will solve your problem.

Example:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk

def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col,
               command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

root = Tk()
columns = ('number',)
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for t in ('1', '10', '11', '2', '3'):
    treeview.insert('', END, values=(t,))
treeview.pack()
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col,
                     command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(treeview, c, False))

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thank you!

Comment: Note that for this to work with multiple columns, you must define the sort command as `command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(treeview, c, False)` otherwise a non-unique column identifier is used.

Comment: @henneray, What's `c` in your comment?

Comment: `c` is just a dummy key word argument that ensures the lambda function uses the instantaneous value of `col`. If you try your code with 2 columns you will see what the issue is. It will try to sort each column using values from only the last for-loop iteration of the col variable. So both columns `['numbers1','numbers2']` would be sorted by values in 'numbers2.

Comment: @henneray, Thank you for the explanation. updated the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: @henneray, I saw your code modification in `treeview_sort_column`; the code there does not share the problem you mentioned as far as I know.

Comment: Ah ok sorry about that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I figure I'd add this bit of code for anyone wanting to use the above solution for both regular string sorts and numeric sorts.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    try:
        l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
        #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    except ValueError:
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add this modification.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is checking in 2020 and need to include float as well, then use this

```
l.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find a variant of this answer, but I thought I would post an answer for those looking to sort dates as a string (i.e. 'DD/MM/YYYY')

```
import datetime

def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(key=lambda: x, datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d/%m/%y'), reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
```