# TTK Treeview not sorting ID numerically

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I recently found a sorting solution for treeview that allows me to sort each record in the table alphabetically, but when I try to sort by ID, which loads in 1-20, it doesn't sort back to 1-20. My code and a screenshot is shown below. The code sorts all of the other columns properly.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
l.sort(reverse=reverse)

# rearrange items in sorted positions
for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
    tv.move(k, '', index)

# reverse sort next time
tv.heading(col, command=lambda:
           treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
for col in tv['columns']:
tv.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col:
           treeview_sort_column(tv, _col, False))
```

This above was not my code, hence why I need help.

Link to screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKb5Y.jpg

EDIT: Link to show full code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9bNn.jpg

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: are you sure you have numbers, not strings with digits "1" - "20" ?

Comment: The values in the table come from a sqlite3 query, and there is one line of code that changes the variable it is stored in explicitly into an integer but no change :(

Comment: it sort like you have strings instead of numbers.

Comment: never put code and error messages as screenshot - we can't copy it to use in answer or comment.

Comment: BTW: can't you get all data in row using one `SELECT * FROM ...`? why do you use `song_int` if you have `i` - you can do `for song_int in range(20))`

Comment: maybe you will have to create new function with `int()` to sort only this column.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a correct answer, it's on this thread:

[python ttk treeview sort numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032152/python-ttk-treeview-sort-numbers)