# Treeview Tuple Sort as String (Wrong Order)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

[image]

Alright, after hours of fiddling around I can't seem to fix this bug.
I've tried changing my types to integers, with key = operator.itemgetter(0) and I've also tried with other fix like using iteration_utilities: chained, functools --> Without success

It returns a list of tuples ex: 
[('27958', 'I008'), ('28497', 'I00C'), ('28652', 'I018'), ('28653', 'I001'), ('28713', 'I009'), ('29262', 'I00A'), ('29448', 'I00B'), ('9234', 'I00D'), ('9250', 'I00E')]
As you can see, the numbers starting by 9 are at the end, I'm assuming because it treats it as a string no matter what.

I'm using the basic Treeview_sort_column function often spoken about, nothing fancy.

```
def treeview_sort_column(t1, col, reverse):
    l = [(t1.set(k, int(col)), k) for k in t1.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse) 
    print(l)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        t1.move(k, '', index)

    t1.heading(col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(t1, _col, not reverse))

for col in columns:
    t1.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(t1, _col, False))
```

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: It should put the Smaller Numbers (9234 and 9250) ahead of larger numbers (27958) in the tuple. [('9234', 'I00D'), ('9250', 'I00E'), ('27958', 'I008'), ('28497', 'I00C'), ('28652', 'I018'), ('28653', 'I001'), ('28713', 'I009'), ('29262', 'I00A'), ('29448', 'I00B')]

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032152/python-ttk-treeview-sort-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ( Just learned it ) it did solve the issue.
It solved all my issues instantly and with simplicity... much easier than all I've tried!

For those looking for the solution

*l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)*