# Tkinter Treeview Quicksort

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter

I've implemented this treeview quicksort algorithm with inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967793/12815969) sort.

I've ran into an issue where the multiple digit values that have the same first digit stack up on each other, I've shown a screenshot of this below.

[image: 1 and 11 shouldn't stack up like that]

I want to have it sorted properly (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11)

I am aware and have used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22032582/12815969) previously, however I do not know how to implement this fix into my quick sort version of the sort.

Here is my code:

```
def sort_upon_press(self, c):
    self.arr = [(self.tree.set(k, c), k) for k in self.tree.get_children('')]
    self.n = len(self.arr)
    self.quickSort(self.tree, c, self.arr, 0, self.n-1, False)

def partition(self, arr,low, high):
    i = (low-1)
    pivot = arr[high]
    print(pivot)
 
    for j in range(low, high):
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
 
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)
 
def quickSort(self, tv, col, arr, low, high, reverse):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if low < high:
        pi = self.partition(arr, low, high)
 
        self.quickSort(tv, col, arr, low, pi-1, reverse=reverse)
        self.quickSort(tv, col, arr, pi+1, high, reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(arr):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
        self.quickSort(tv, col, arr, low, high, not reverse))
    if reverse == True:
        arr_reverse = arr[::-1]
        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(arr_reverse):
            tv.move(k, '', index)
```

Comment: Your values are sorted as strings not numbers. Do you always have integers in the column or can it be strings as well?

Comment: @j_4321 In this column, there are only integers.

Comment: Then convert the value to `int` before sorting

Comment: @j_4321 what value?

Comment: I am passing in the tree ID of the row and sorting it by attaching/dettaching where the values are supposed to go in order. The tree IDs show up as values like `I001` or `I002`, but the value `11` shows as tree ID: `I00A`, which is throwing my system off. I have to make sure the sort sees the value as an integer, but I don't know how I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the items are not in the expected order is because they are sorted as string and not as integers. This can be fixed by converting the value of the item to int in `sort_upon_press()`:

```
def sort_upon_press(self, c):
    self.arr = [(int(self.tree.set(k, c)), k) for k in self.tree.get_children('')]
    self.n = len(self.arr)
    self.quickSort(self.tree, c, self.arr, 0, self.n-1, False)
```