# Tkinter Treeview Column Sorting

Tags: python, sqlite, sorting, tkinter, treeview

Is there a way to sort the records in a Tk Treeview by clicking the column?

I have a Treeview database table displayed in a Tkinter module. The database is linked to a SQLite database where the data is sourced.

Comment: (Sounds trivial, depending on what exactly `by clicking the column` means: please elaborate.)

Comment: Hi @greybeard I mean when you click on the column heading, it will sort that column ascendingly, or descendingly. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old but it's a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort) so maybe some one with more reputation can tag it.

Answer (score 2):

@Mayur had the right idea, just missed including the definition of `treeview_sort_column`. I can vouch for the technique, though I implemented the call differently than the command option. You can review it at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort) as well (though it may die in the future)

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
           treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
[...]
columns = ('name', 'age')
treeview = ttk.TreeView(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda: \
                     treeview_sort_column(treeview, col, False))
[...]
```