# Referencing ttk.Treeview columns from another function

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to order my ttk.Treeview using this code:

```
for col in columns:
    AttendanceView.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=("patrol"): \
        ttk.treeview_sort_column(AttendanceView, _col, False))
```

My problem is that I cannot reference the columns in the for loop, as these lines of code are in a separate function to that of where the Treeview is defined. The treeview is called `AttendanceView`

I have tried:

```
for col in AttendanceView.columns:
for col in treeview.columns:
columns= AttendanceView.get_columns()
```

Comment: If `AttendanceView` is the instance of your `Treeview` widget use `AttendanceView['columns']`. Second, this: `_col=("patrol")`; will fail as you assign a `tuple` instead of `str`.

Comment: Read [tutorial/tree.html](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Comment: @stovfl So like this then: `for col in AttendanceView['columns']:
  AttendanceView.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
   ttk.treeview_sort_column(AttendanceView, _col, False))`

Comment: The code you posted above, leaves a lot to the imagination. You should post the relevant parts of your code to prevent guesses. Post both functions that show what you are trying to call and where you are trying to call it from(at the least)

Comment: There ist **no** `ttk.treeview_sort_column(...`! Read the **whole* Q&A, you should implement it like in the [accepted Answer - Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967793/7414759),  you have copied from.