# How do you sort a treeview by column?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to sort a treeview widget by a column. Specifically I want to sort the treeview via the column patrols.

```
    # Add Sorting
    l = [(AttendanceView.set(k, AttendanceView['columns'][2]), k) for k in AttendanceView.get_children('')]
    print("In sort")
    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        AttendanceView.move(k, '', index)
```

The Line:

```
print(AttendanceView['columns'])
```

yields:

```
('firstname', 'secondname', 'patrol', 'present')
```

Comment: Checked this [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

Comment: @ChuckG I have looked at this and have implemented it in my program, however my desired outcome is just to have the treeview organised by the Patrol collumn upon initialising it. In the solution you have linked to, the OP wanted to order his treeview by column upon the users command (clicking the column). I just want the treeview to be ordered.