# Sorting a ttk.treeview record

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, treeview

I am a beginner in python please help me how I can sort rows in treeview , I want read data from excel and show them in the sorted list in treeview
now its output is like photo that I want to sort by id

```
enter code here 
def show_data():
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('F:\python project\Form1.xlsx')
   sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
   lb.delete(*lb.get_children())
   for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=0):
        lb.insert('', 'end', values=[cell.value for cell in row])
cols = ('name', 'ID', 'Mark')
lb=ttk.Treeview(frame1, columns=cols, show='headings')
for col in cols:
    lb.heading(col, text=col)
Button(frame2, text='show DB', command=show_data).grid(row=0, column=2, 
sticky=W, pady=4)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUskV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

Comment: I saw this answer it not work

Comment: Which part did not work? Did you follow the other answer which works for python 3?

Comment: I want to sort the data by their id values, but when I add this code to my code nothing happens, and again the data is unordered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the pasted link already had the answer, but the sorting does seem to be unordered if the column to be sorted are numbers. Here's how to sort it correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self,master,**kw):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self,master,**kw)
        header = ("ID", "Column 2","Column 3")
        width = (100,100,100)
        self["columns"] = header
        for i in range(len(header)):
            self.column(header[i], width=width[i], anchor="w")
            self.heading(header[i], text=header[i], anchor='w')

        self.heading("ID", text="ID", command=lambda _col="ID": self.tree_sort(self, _col, False))

    def tree_sort(self, tv, col, reverse):
        l = [(int(tv.set(k, col)), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)

        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
            tv.move(k, '', index)

        tv.heading(col, command=lambda: self.tree_sort(tv, col, not reverse))

tree = MyTree(root,height=20)
tree.pack()

for i in range(50):
    tree.insert("",0,text=f"Test{i}",values=(i,f"Test String {i}",f"Amount {i}"))

root.mainloop()
```