# Python Tkinter Treeview sort column when clicked on the column header

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote this procedure (python 3.8 which will display any dataframe in a tkinter treeview. How can I bind a click on the table header to sort the table when clicked.

```
def view_dfs(df1):
    df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    table = tk.Tk()
    table.geometry("1220x500")
    table.pack_propagate(False)
    table.resizable(0, 0)

    frame = tk.LabelFrame(table, text="Report")
    frame.place(height=485, width=1200)

    # Treeview Widget
    tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame, style="mystyle.Treeview")
    tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

    treescrolly = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview)
    treescrollx = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview)
    tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)
    treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    
    def Load_excel_df1():
        tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
        tv1["column"] = list(df1.columns)
        tv1["show"] = "headings"
        for column in tv1["columns"]:
            tv1.column(column, width = 100) 
            tv1.heading(column, text=column)

        df_rows = df1.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            tv1.insert("", "end", values=row)
        return

    def exit_window():
        table.destroy()
        return

    Load_excel_df1()
    table.mainloop()
    return
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tk treeview column sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort)

Answer (score -1):

```
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame, style="mystyle.Treeview", show="headings")
```

A)

```
for a in range(5):
    tv1.heading('#'+str(kol), text="a"+str(a), \
    command= lambda c=a: selc(c))

def selc(c):
    print('c '+str(c))
```

B)

```
for a in range(5):
    tv1.heading('#'+str(a), text="#"+str(a))
tv1.bind ('<ButtonRelease-1>', sel)
def sel(b):
    z = tv1.identify("region", b.x, b.y)
    if z == 'heading':
        print('A')
    if z == 'cell':
        print('B')
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is an [English-Only](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) site. Please edit your answer to English.